# How can I test for birch log in Minecraft 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I get my command block to test for a birch log in 1.8? What are the new item names?

I have already tried names like "birch_log", "17:2", "log:2" and so on. Google is against me on this as well.

Comment: Those sounds like the right sort of things to be searching for, are you sure the rest of your command is correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
/testforblock x y z minecraft:log 2
```

2 for facing up/down, 6 for facing east/west, 10 for facing north/south, 14 for with only bark.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft 1.13 removed the concept of data values, making commands like this much simpler:

```
/execute if block x y z minecraft:birch_log
```

(`/testforblock` was merged into `/execute`)